# Не могу понять почему процедура не принимает значение из функции

Tags: delphi

```
function Slovo1 (a , b : string): string;

begin
 a := 'qwer';
 b := 'rtyu';
 result := a + b;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
ShowMessage(Slovo1 (result));
end;
```

Почему ругается на `result` в `ShowMessage(Slovo1 (result));`?

Comment: Неправильно пользуетесь функцией
ShowMessage(Slovo1 ('Привет ', 'мир'));

Comment: @NMD Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `Slovo1` ошибочно вызывается как `Slovo1(result)`, хотя она должна принимать два строковых параметра.